# Redis -How to Get Last 1hour Data from redis

Tags: redis

How to get all the keys/data stored in "redis" in the last one hour. I searched to found it out, but couldn't find a way. Is there any way to get this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis does not have a direct way to do this.

Depending on your use case, in increasing order of complexity -

1. You can manually add newly created keys to a set. The name of the set can include the timestamp. You can then query this set to find keys that have been modified
2. You can use redis keyspace notification to get notified of keys when they are changed. However, be aware that pub/sub notifications are "fire and forget" - so if your connection drops - you will lose some of the keys that were updated.
3. You can look at the AOF file and identify keys that have been created / modified. If you are using a cloud provider for redis - they may not provide access to the AOF file. Also, the AOF file doesn't have the timestamp, but the commands are in the order they were processed by redis.